# Boot Linux from a GPT disk using SYSLINUX

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, gpt, syslinux

From [Booting from GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/booting.html), it says that both Grub & syslinux support booting Linux from a GPT disk. Anyone knows how exactly can I use syslinux to boot Linux from a GPT disk please?

The article says

> *The SYSLINUX boot loader is another Linux boot loader that includes GPT support. This support resides in the MBR and redirects the boot process to a partition with the Legacy BIOS Bootable flag set*

But that seems to me is defeating the claim that syslinux support GPT booting, because if the support resides only in the MBR, and also need a Legacy BIOS partition with Bootable flag set for it to work, then with my GPT disk lacks of both of them, does it mean syslinux can't boot my machine?